# React Native Navigation 2

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

i try update to RNN2 and implement this in App.js like this:

```
Navigation.registerComponent("Screen.AlertScreen", () => AlertScreen);
Navigation.registerComponent("Screen.OverlayScreen", () => OverlayScreen);
Navigation.registerComponent("Screen.SigninScreen", () => SigninScreen, store, Provider);

export default () => Navigation.events().registerAppLaunchedListener(() => {
     Navigation.setRoot({
        root: {
           component: {
              name: 'Screen.SigninScreen'
           }
        }
     });
});
```

But i get this error:
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {remove}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Hi did you get any further on this?